# React app - how to identify undefined object in the code?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to React, so hopefully it's not a silly question but I have been getting the error below when I ran the code. [image]

I believe the error is related to one of the two files' codes below. Can someone help me to see where I'm making a mistake?

**App.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BusinessList from '../BusinessList/BusinessList';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';

const business = { imageSrc: 
'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/programs/react/ravenous/pizza.jpg',
name: 'MarginOtto Pizzeria',
address: '1010 Paddington Way',
city: 'Flavortown',
state: 'NY',
zipCode: '10101',
category: 'Italian',
rating: 4.5,
reviewCount: 90};

const businesses = [business,business,business,business,business,business];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
  <h1>ravenous</h1>
  <SearchBar />
  <BusinessList businesses={businesses} />
</div>
);}}


export default App;
```

**Business.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Business.css';
import '../App/App'

class Business extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { business } = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="Business">
        <div className="image-container">
          <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/programs/react/ravenous/pizza.jpg' alt=''/>
        </div>
        <h2>{business.name}</h2>
        <div className="Business-information">
          <div className="Business-address">
            <p>{business.address}</p>
            <p>{business.city}</p>
            <p>{business.state} {business.zipCode}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="Business-reviews">
            <h3>{business.category}</h3>
            <h3 className="rating">{business.rating} stars</h3>
            <p>{business.reviewCount} reviews</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
}

export default Business;
```

Comment: I think more likely the error is in the component BusinessList, can you share the code for that as well?

Comment: It didn't let me add more code so hopefully it's readible: `import React from 'react';
import './BusinessList.css';
import Business from '../Business/Business';

class BusinessList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="BusinessList">
        {
            this.props.businesses.map((business)=>{
                return <Business business={this.business} />;})
        }
        </div>   
        );
    }
}

export default BusinessList;`

Comment: Your issue is using {this.business} when it should just be {business}, consider adding ESLint to help you catch unused variables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in your `BusinessList` component.

you pass `this.business` as a prop to `Business` but it should just be `business` (*the name of the parameter use in the `.map` function*)

```
import React from "react";
import "./BusinessList.css";
import Business from "../Business/Business";
class BusinessList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BusinessList">
        {this.props.businesses.map(business => {
          return <Business business={business} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default BusinessList;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Business.js file try to change code like this

```
return business && (
    ...
);
```

if business is undefine then it returns null.
Or if it doesn't work try to use ?: operator like

```
return business ? (...) : null;
```

Hope this help you to resolve issue

Comment: While this is a good way to make code more "error" proof, I think the real answer should be to first understand WHY it is undefined (code error or business error). If it is expected that the business could be null/undefined then this is a good solution but if it should never be null this just hides the errors.

Comment: Yes correct answer is business={business} instead of this.business. I didn't look at the updated comments in the issue so I suggested above code snippet.